# Recognize when Twitter and Facebook is acessing the posted/tweeted URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook, twitter

I'm working on an URL shortener that keeps track of how many times a link was clicked.

However, I'm running into a problem where both Twitter and Facebook will access the URL a few times once it is published. Twitter opens it 6 times, and Facebook only twice.

How can I know when they're the ones following through the URL so I can avoid counting their accesses?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try detecting the User-Agent HTTP header if the request are made from facebook or twitter bots it should be different.

Comment: Is there a specific way to know when it is a bot? If so, it's best to disallow all of them. Otherwise I guess I'll set up a link to grab the user agent and trick Twitter into following it.

Comment: There are no specific way as evey bot can set what it wants. You should try make them following a link to track their http headers, there might be some others interesting header no present from browsers requests.